# How can I make a score for a number based on how close it is to the mode of a list and how frequently it occurs in the list?

Tags: python

I am trying to score distances in a list on how close they are to the mode of the list and also based on how often they occur in the list. The score is out of 1. I can not seem to get it to work where the score is an accurate representation of its value within the list.
I have been trying this code.

```
def calc_racedistance_likeability_score(race_dist,list_of_distances):
    list_of_distances = [10, 5,5,5,5, 10, 16.09, 10, 10.7, 10,
                   10, 5, "Marathon", 15, 10, 10, 5, 10,
                   15, 10, 10,10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]

#calculate mode to get users most chosen race
    most_chosen_distance = statistics.mode(list_of_distances)    #get mode of list 

    if race_dist == most_chosen_distance:
        score = 1
    else:
        frequency_score = (list_of_distances.count(race_dist) / len(list_of_distances))
        accuracy_score = score = 1 - abs(race_dist - most_chosen_distance) / (race_dist + most_chosen_distance)
        score = (frequency_score * accuracy_score)

    print(f"score is {score}...for distance {race_dist}")
```

Ideally the score should be weighted in favor of lower numbers, slightly (distance 9 would get a better score than distance 11 if 10 was the mode) and the score should be weighted towards how frequently it occurs over how close it is to the mode. How can I go round making this work, to get a score where closest to 1 is best.

Comment: What does your expected output look like for the unique entries of this list?

Comment: I don't think this question belongs on this site.  If I understand you, you are having trouble thinking of an algorithm that produces values that you like.  This site is where you would go to get help _implementing_ the algorithm.

Comment: can you give example of expected input and output ?

Comment: @nisakova, the expected input is a distance - any number 1-100really, then based on the elements in the list, it will give it a score. the score will depend on 1. how similar the input is to the mode of the list. 2. how frequently the input occurs in the list.